# How to share a common mapping template at AWS API Gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm having a lot of duplicated mapping templates across endpoints on my AWS API Gateway implementation.

I would like to have a single template defined, and then just tell an endpoint to use that particular template.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported, but definitely something we can consider in the future as we update the service.

**Update**: My apologies. Templates ***are*** exposed as their [own resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/template/). Can you tell me how you are creating your API? I may be able to advise on how to re-use them correctly.